# How to sovle problem of pyswip fatal error

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Has retrieved the most recent version of SWI-Prolog from the designated download page, http://www.swi-prolog.org/Download.html, and has completed its installation.

Has ensured that the swipl executable is included in the PATH environment variable.
However, “Could not find system resources”.

from pyswip import Prolog